# Symfony4 Twig Path with ParamConverter Annotation

Tags: php, symfony, url, twig

I have a Controller with a `ParamConverter` annotation that is perfectly working :

```
/**
* @Route("/pro/{uniqid}")
* @ParamConverter("company", options={"mapping":{"uniqid" = "uniqid"}})
* Class AdminController
* @package App\Controller
*/
class AdminController extends Controller
{}
```

And inside I have a method with another `ParamConverter` annotation :

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/{user-uniqid}/edit", name="edit-user")
 * @ParamConverter("user", options={"mapping":{"user-uniqid" = "uniqid"}})
 * @param Company $company
 * @param User $user
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editUser(Company $company, User $user){}
```

Bu in `Twig` when I use `path` like that :

```
<a href="{{ path('edit-user', {'uniqid' : company.uniqid, 'user-uniqid' : permission.user.uniqid}) }}">Edit</a>
```

Instead of creating a link like

```
http://symfony/pro/cie5aee957cc7a6d/admin/user-5aee93691d3a6/edit
```

It creates this link :

```
http://symfony/pro/cie5aee957cc7a6d/admin/%7Buser-uniqi%7D/edit?user-uniqid=user-5aee93691d3a6
```

I can't explain why `{user-uniqid}` is not properly filled and why a new query parameter is created...

Comment: Stupid question, but there is a typo in your code snippet in the route: `{user-uniqi}` the last letter is missing. Is this an actual error or a copy-paste-thing?

Comment: yup, sorry, copy/paste mistake. I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, i solved it by replacing the hyphen by an underscore in the variable name.

Try this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/{user_uniqid}/edit", name="edit-user")
 * @ParamConverter("user", options={"mapping":{"user_uniqid" = "uniqid"}})
 * ...
 */
```

Comment: Wtf. I'd like if that kind of weird behaviour could be noticed in the documentation. Thank you very much, I love SO.